# Where can I find anime dubbed into English with Spanish subtitles?

Tags: resources, streaming-sites

By any chance, is there a website that has anime dubbed into English but with Spanish subtitles?

I think Crunchyroll works, only right now I don't have the money to have an account.

I wanted to see *Hunter x Hunter* or *Death Note* not only in Japanese (well, subtitled). But I am not very good with English.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Comment: Every anime on Netflix is dubbed into English, with several different language options for subtitles. I believe Spanish is among them, but I'll have to check before I post this as an answer. I don't believe Netflix has *Hunter x Hunter* or *Death Note*, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Netflix or Hulu. Some of those animes that you're looking for are on there and may have the option to have Spanish subtitles as well.

Every so often, they update their library and add new animes or may take some old ones away. So, while *Hunter x Hunter* may not be there now, it might there in the future or may have been recently added. It's the same with Hulu.

For *Death Note*, I just checked, and yes, the complete 2006-07 anime adaptation is available on Netflix. All 37 episodes, which are each around 20 minutes long.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want something that specific, then Crunchyroll is probably the only available legal site for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch it legally. This applications allow that, like Netflix or Crunchyroll. You'll probably won't find any free site for that, because the people that make this sites (I'm one so I can tell) only make this sites for their own language. This means that if they want to watch it in English, they won't post any eps in spanish